# Best practice to prevent other users viewing/editing each other data

Tags: laravel-4

I am new to Laravel and was wondering what would; be the best practice to prevent users editing each other data.

I am aware that I can handle users pages with filter and Auth, eg.

```
 Route::filter('auth', function($route)
   {
    $id = $route->getParameter('id');
     if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id != $id) {

      return Redirect::route('forbidden');
   }
});
```

However I was wondering what about relationship pages (i.e. /user_profile/14, user_settings/22 , etc ). Do I have define filter for each of these [group of] routes and check id's against the relationship?? e.g.

```
Route::filter('auth.user_settings', function($route)
{
    $id = $route->getParameter('id');
     if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->user_settings->id != $id) {

      return Redirect::route('forbidden');
  });

Route::filter('auth.user_profile', function($route)
{
    $id = $route->getParameter('id');
     if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->profile->id != $id) {

      return Redirect::route('forbidden');
  });

 ...etc
```

or is there a better way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you did your application in a way that your route might look like this:

```
Route::get('user_profile/{id}', function()
```

If that's how you've been defining the routes for your user you might want to change it to just:

```
Route::get('user_profile', function()
```

Then upon requesting, the controllers would then load the appropriate profile/setting from the current authenticated user using something like **Profile::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id)** which in this case you don't have to worry about user checking out others profile, and all you need is the **'auth'** filter group for the routes.

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid. In my defense, it was a long day, dont know what i was thinking,. lo. thanks